# EJB3.1 Providing property value

Tags: ejb-3.1

Maybe this question could be duplicated. I just can't find any good search words.

How can I provide some development property value to SLSBs?

```java
@LocalBean
@Stateless
class ClouldBean {

    public void doSomethingWithUsernameAndPassowrd() {
        // ...
    }

    private String username;
    private String password;
}
```

I just want to know how to inject `username` and `password` in a very **standard** and **portable** way.

Do I have to use some standard property configuration file?

Do I have to set it be contracted as being provided by container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is standard and portable way and it is called environment entry.

Add following to ejb-jar.xml:

```
<ejb-jar>
    <enterprise-beans>
         ....
        <session>
            <ejb-name>ClouldBean</ejb-name>
         ....
            <env-entry>
               <env-entry-name>username</env-entry-name>
               <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
               <env-entry-value>my name</env-entry-value>
            </env-entry>
        ...
        </session>
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

And then you can inject value to the variable in your bean:

```
@Resource(name="username")
private String username;
```

For more detailed example you can take a look to this [blog post](http://javaevangelist.blogspot.de/2008/08/how-to-implement-ejb-30-in-ejb-jarxml.html).  For all the details best source is EJB 3.1 specification section 16.4.

Comment: Is it possible to modify these values in runtime?

Comment: In general no it is not. For reason ejb-jar.xml is called deployment descriptor. Of course some implementation can support such a functionality (as a accidental side effect or by purpose), but even in best case it is not portable behavior.

Comment: Again, Ich bin Ihnen sehr dankbar.

Comment: I think you might be interested in [DeltaSpike](http://incubator.apache.org/projects/deltaspike.html) project or in some simple solution which you can provide by yourself like [this one](http://piotrnowicki.com/2012/06/inject-java-properties-in-java-ee-using-cdi/)